# why is my codespace of CS50 not letting me put breakpoints to use debug50?

Tags: cs50, codespaces

so Im studying computer science with CS50 from Harvardx Courses.
There they provide an online codespace running vscode with some pre-installed expansions.
and in the lecture the teatcher tought us how to use the breakpoints to debug, by clicking in the red ball on the side of the line.

But in my codespace there is no red ball when i hover the mouse to the side of the line.
there isn`t even space to place a red point there.

[image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrWlk.png)

what can I do? Because its a really good tool for debugging

I didnt tried much things because I dont know what can be.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and it drove me insane for about 10mins so here's my solution if you, future reader, also have this problem

In the top left corner of the codespace:

```
Go to File > Preferences > Settings
```

Look for "breakpoint"
check the box for "Debug: Allow breakpoints everywhere" in the "[codespaces]" tab